# Help identify a 2000-2016s scifi movie about visiting an alien planet that turns out to be Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's set on an Earthlike planet that later turns out to actually be Earth. The main thing I can remember is the main character encounters some sort of 4-legged walking drone that we assume is alien but it turns its head and reveals a Union Jack on it and is clearly a military drone.

The story has a big reveal in it where we go into some military base and learn the planet has pretty much self-destructed because a space ship appeared in the sky one day... which turns out to be us... and then it turns out this is Earth and we caused our own destruction.

I think it was one of those movies that went straight to Netflix or Amazon and has about four cast members in it at most.

Comment: [Relevant TvTropes link](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarthAllAlong).  Yeah, it's a really common "twist ending".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [Robot World](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4083740/) (2015)

> A pilot is marooned on an alien planet and soon discovers the planet is inhabited by predatory machines.

The nightmarish dystopian hellscape turns out to be

> A fairly accurate representation of modern-day Birmingham

Comment: Birmingham is also the inspiration for Mordor, so it fits.

Comment: @Separatrix - It always surprised me that Tolkien made Mordor look so warm and inviting by comparison.